# how do i completely uninstall tencent gamming buddy

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I'm using tencent gaming buddy for playing PUBG mobile on my windows 10 pc
yesterday my emulator got corrupted and start saying "failed to start the emulator the emulator was not properly closed" so I started searching how to fix it and found uninstall and delete data of emulator an reinstall the emulator is the only way to fix it

my question is how to delete data of tencent gaming buddy after uninstalling?
if there is any other way of fixing it then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

When you search for TGB on start menu, right click on the app and there should be an uninstall command as well. After deleting that, you might want to delete these as well :

Go to C:/Programdata and search for Txgameassistant or something related to tencent and delete the folder. the programdata folder is hidden by default, so either type the address in address bar or unhide system folders/hidden folders.

Look for a "Temp" folder created in whichever drive of yours has the most free space and delete the folder.

Go to C:/Users/(your username)/Appdata and you will see three folders, Roaming, [https://gameloop.mobi](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJNyzh7aS57DDltNMzYpF8g) local or something like that..look for tencent related folders in all those and delete them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the AOW Process. AOW is Turbo Process for Gamebuddy. Download the [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) and search for **aow** process by typing it in top right corner of Process Hacker and Terminate it. Restart the Emulator and you will be good to go.

Comment: I will test it out, for now somehow it started working again, but still appreciated your answer, keep helping others with proud